# launching new activity with the tabbar environment

Tags: android, tabs

```
     host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("Offers")
            .setIndicator("Offers", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_light))
            .setContent(new Intent(this, List_Items.class)));


       host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("Account")
            .setIndicator("Account", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_wrench))
            .setContent(new Intent(this, Offer_Popup.class)));


   BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String action=intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals("newstuff"))
            {

                 Intent intent2= new Intent(context, NewStuff.class);
                 startActivity(intent2);
            }

        }

        };


    IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter("newstuff");
    this.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);
```

Right Now, I have 2 tabs in the tabbars environment, and also there's a broadcast listener that if matched "newstuff" action then it will launch a NewStuff class activity but this way, it's covering up my tab bar environment. How do I launch the new activity from listener such that it won't cover my tabbars?